# The Captain's Log is shown like a narrative; how is it recorded?

Tags: star-trek

Memory Alpha has this to say about the [Captain's Log](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Captain's_log)

> Presumably, these log entries were created after the events had transpired, when the captain had time to update his log, and it was either Starfleet procedure or just Kirk's personal habit to record such logs in the present tense.

Is the recording done by the computer in his quarters? Or is there a recording device, like on his wrist?

Comment: Related, kinda: [When/How would Star Trek captains update their log?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24613/98028)

Comment: It wasn't just Kirk's habit. Picard and other members of the crew also often narrated their logs in present tense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The bridge log is on the [Astrogator](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Astrogator) on the module front of Kirk's big chair (between the two stations used by the helmsman and navigator).

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Starfleet Technical Manual**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual)</sup></sub>

You can see it in this reverse-shot of the bridge.

[image]

---

There was also a log access on the computer in his quarters.

[image]

Comment: A Ship's Log is completely different from a Captain's Log (i.e. recorded journal of events). A [ship's log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_log) is an instrument that measures the distance travelled, otherwise known as an odometer on land vehicles.

Comment: In "Dagger of the Mind" (TOS S01E11) Kirk is seen updating his log at about 15:45, as they return to Tantalus V: *"Captain's log, stardate 2715.2. Standard orbit, planet Tantalus V.  Mission, routine investigation and report as per ship surgeon's medical log"* - he then turns off recorder, hands it to a crewman, and calls Sickbay

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203697/the-captains-log-is-shown-like-a-narrative-how-is-it-recorded/203699#203699), one can also mention the portable logbook used in the Kirk era and seen in the movies:

- In *Star Trek V: The Ultimate Frontier*, it is held by an Ensign and seems to have underwent the same retrofit than the Enterprise, with similar results.

[image: Log Recorder]

- In *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*, it is held by the First Officer when Captain Sulu makes his log entry at the beginning of the movie, just moments before the Excelsior is hit by the shockwave from the explosion of Praxis.

[image]

Those seem to have fallen out of use by the time of TNG, as advances in technology now allow people to simply record their logs by talking to the computer directly and announcing if they are recording an officer log or a personal log.

Answer (score 0):

In Star Trek deep space nine episode in a pale moonlight sisko dose a Captain's personal log,
Where he tells how he got the Romulans to join the war.
Other time when people make logs they just talking to the computer and then it's recorded and saved. 
There have been some episodes where there's been a situation and someone has come to investigate and has permission to access logs and you see them reading them on a Pad.

Comment: OP was asking about Kirk's log although a wider perspective is also useful

Comment: The question at the top of the page says Captain's Log how is it  recorded. I didn't realise it was specific to Captain Kirk.

Comment: The question does specifically mention Kirk; "*Presumably, these log entries were created after the events had transpired, when the captain had time to update his log, and it was either Starfleet procedure or just **Kirk's personal habit to record such logs in the present tense**.*" - As I said, it's useful to get an idea of how it's done before/after the Kirk era.

Comment: Been better if someone just wrote how does Captain Kirk record he's captain's log? Lol